# Python - How to use multiprocessing Lock in class instance?

Tags: python-3.x, locking, python-multiprocessing, python-3.7

I am using Python 3.7 on Windows.

What I am trying to do:
- lock a method of an instance of a class, when another process has acquired that same lock.

Attempts:

I have already successfully done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276933/python-multiprocessing-lock-issue), but I don't want a global variable here for the lock, but instead one completely internal to the class

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, freeze_support,Pool
from time import sleep

def do_work(name):
    print(name+' waiting for lock to work...',end='')
    sleep(2)
    with lock:
        print('done!')
        print(name+' doing work...',end='')
        sleep(5)
        print('done!')

def init(olock):
    global lock
    lock = olock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    args_list = [('a'),('b'),('c')]
    lock=Lock()
    p=Pool(8,initializer=init,initargs=(lock,))
    p.map_async(do_work,args_list)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

When this last chunk of code runs, it takes **~17.3 seconds**, because of the lock. Without the lock it takes **~7 seconds**.

I have tried to implement this inside a class, but the lock does nothing, and it always runs in **~7 seconds**.

```
class O():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock=Lock()
    def __getstate__(self): # used to remove multiprocess object(s) from class, so it can be pickled
        self_dict=self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['lock']
        return self_dict
    def __setstate__(self,state): # used to remove multiprocess object(s) from class, so it can be pickled
        self.__dict__.update(state)
    def _do_work(self,name):
        print(name+' waiting for lock to work...',end='')
        sleep(2)
        with self.lock:
            print('done!')
            print(name+' doing work...',end='')
            sleep(5)
            print('done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    c = O()
    pool = Pool(8)
    pool.apply_async(c._do_work,('a',))
    pool.apply_async(c._do_work,('b',))
    pool.apply_async(c._do_work,('c',))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Question:
So, what can I do to lock up this class instance while I call a method which interacts with a resource asynchronously through multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply_async` will pickle function object and send to pool worker process by queue, but as `c._do_work` is a bound method, the instance will be pickled too, which results in an error. you could wrap it within a plain function:

```
c = O()
def w(*args):
    return c._do_work(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(1)
    pool.apply_async(w, ('a',))
    ...
```

and you should remove `__setstate__`/`__getstate__`.